# JSR303 - Validate Only if Populated

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I have a field in a Java Bean (kilograms) that is not mandatory, but if the user does enter it, it obviously needs to be a number.

Is there a combination of JSR303 annotations that can enforce that rule?  I tried

```
@Min(value=0)
```

But that obviously disallows empty, which is allowable.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do a OR composition with Bean Validation 1.0. Hibernate Validator has a feature which allows you do so. It is called "boolean composition of custom constraints" - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e3701

So you need a custom constraint and you obviously won't be standard conform, but it works.

For Bean Validation 1.1 there is a discussion whether boolean composition should make it into the standard ([BVAL-260](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/BVAL-260)), but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that null values are considered valid. See

http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/bean-validation-api/1.0/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html

You need to use object types (Integer) instead of primitive types. If you have problems with it please show us your bean.